# Stat failed for uploaded files

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the last modification time to display when the file(s) were uploaded, but I am getting this error: Warning: stat(): stat failed for image.jpeg in /var/www/html/module/Admin/File.php on line 116

Here is the code that handles it:

```
public function getModificationTime($dir)
{
    if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        return false;
    }

    $scandir = scandir($dir);

    $holder = array();

    foreach ($scandir as $key => $values) {
        $holder = stat($values);
    }

    return $holder;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not related, but you need `$holder[] = stat($values);` to avoid overwriting your previous results.

Comment: Are you sure that the path is either absolute or if relative then relative to the script path correctly? And of course, if the file exists?

Comment: yeah, I didn't have the dir included, it works but is throwing an error -- Notice: Undefined index: mtime in /var/www/html/module/Admin/view/admin/admin/upload.phtml on line 63

Answer (score 1):

`stat()` cannot find the file. Use the full path (`$values` contains only the file name):

```
$holder = stat($dir.'/'.$values);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Now though I am running into an error that says: Notice: Undefined index: mtime in /var/www/html/module/Admin/view/admin/admin/upload.phtml on line 63

I checked php.net and it says stat has a index mtime in the results..

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the directory name. It's looking for the file in the current directory, not the directory you're scanning.

```
$holder = stat($dir . '/' . $values);
```